# PHP Excel - Center Across Selection

Tags: php, phpexcel

I need to center a text from A to O columns without merging them. I know I have option of Center Across selection in Excel, but how to do that in PHPExcel?

I need to do the following tasks in the excel sheet

```
A) Center Across Selection
B) Insert a TextBox so I can place that anywhere
C) Insert a shape
```

[image]

**EDIT**

I dont know why i got negative points, but my questions are valid and there is no help on the internet, so if it is not supported yet, then also let me know.

**EDIT 2**

I found that using use HORIZONTAL_CENTER_CONTINUOUS for center across selection works. Now I need to insert TextBox and Shape

Comment: Simply put, PHPExcel doesn't support TextBoxes or Shapes, so you can't do either of those

Comment: Hmm, can I open an excel file with text input and shape and then update few cells... will that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need form input and shapes then you're very limited in your options. The only ones that I'm aware of are PHP's [COM extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.com.php), which requires a COM enabled spreadsheet program such as MS Excel or OpenOffice Calc running on the server; the Open Office alternative to COM ([PUNO](http://www.wstech2.net/index.php?do=0a,01,05)), which requires Open Office installed on the server with Java support enabled; and [Ilia Alshanetsky's Excel extension](https://ilia.ws/archives/222-PHP-Excel-Extension.html) from [github](https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel), that requires the commercial [libXL component](http://www.libxl.com/) installed on your server.